# How to append items to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following:

```
myObject = {
  id: user.id,
  email: user.email,
}
```

I need to add values like so:

```
if current_user && current_user.id == user.id
  myObject << {
    notification_email: user.notification_email,
    notification_email2: user.notification_email2
  }
end
```

The code above raises an error.

What's the right way to optionally append values to the object?

**ERROR**

undefined method `<<' for # Did you mean? <

Comment: What do you mean to **optionally** append values?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't see an array anywhere in your code. `myObject` is a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html).

Comment: @sawa by optionally, I mean only if that if statement is true in my controller, do I want to add the two extra fields.

Comment: Just added the error message

Comment: @AnApprentice use `myObject.merge(your_hash)` because `<<` is not a `Hash` method (use `merge!` to modify the same hash and not return a new one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you want `Hash#merge`.

```
myObject.merge(
  notification_email: user.notification_email,
  notification_email2: user.notification_email2
)
```

If you want side effects, use the banged version.

```
myObject.merge!(
  notification_email: user.notification_email,
  notification_email2: user.notification_email2
)
```

Comment: thanks but that did not add the values... it had no effect

Comment: I added that part.

Comment: @AnApprentice It does not modify the original object, but produced a copy of it with the new elements added. use the bang `!` version to modify the original object in place

Comment: @AnApprentice but if you're adding these elements to a params hash, you might want to leave the original params hash unchanged. you can pass the whole expression as an argument to another method e.g. `Object.create(object_params.merge(new_key: 'new_value'))`

Answer (score 4):

`myObject` is a *hash*, so to add new items you can do this:

```
if current_user && current_user.id == user.id
  myObject[:notification_email] = user.notification_email
  myObject[:notification_email2] = user.notification_email2
end
```